# Importing 3rd party libraries into an android project using eclipse

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, rest

I am working on a project that requires RESTful API communication with a JSON server and will be using a 3rd party library to do this. I have found Ion on github and my server developer and I agree that it meets our needs. Being new to android programming, I am not entirely sure how to import the files into my workspace in a manner that does not cause many errors to occur. Any help, whether it be using a different library or suggestions on how to fix this is problem are welcome.

The link to Ion on [github](https://github.com/koush/ion#get-ion)

I know that on the github page it has a short explanation on how to install, but after trying a couple those the project seemed to reject the imported code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

1.)File->New->Other

2.)Select Android Project

3.)Select "Create Project from existing source"

4.)Click "Browse..." button and navigate to your project

5.)Finish (Now action bar project in your workspace)

6.)Right-click on your project -> Properties

7.)In Android->Library section click Add

8.)select recently added project -> Ok

after done it you have to build your project.
Now it'll be ready to use.